# How do I get rid of these current errors?

Tags: c, pointers, routes, ip

This is my program so far, unfortunately I've gotten some errors, and I don't know how to solve them. I'm not really good with programming so if someone could help me out that would be nice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"


void Ouccpy_Routing_Table();

typedef struct RTE
{
    unsigned long Dest;
    int port;
    int netport;
};

Route[120];

struct IP
{
unsigned char Ipverison;
unsigned char TOS;
short ID;
short Fragoffset;
unsigned char TTL;
unsigned char Protcl;
short dcheksum;
unsigned char Data[1];

}; RTE;

int main()
{
int count;


FILE *ptr_testfile;

struct IP my_testfile;

ptr_testfile = fopen("C:\\ROUTE\\TEST ROUTE.txt", "rb");

if (!ptr_testfile)
{
    printf("Cannot Open File!");

    return 0;
}

}

void Ouccpy_Routing_Table(int IPAddress, int IP_Dest, int route)
{
IPAddress = IP_Dest;

if (CLASS_A(IPAddress)) Mask:(0xff0000000);
if (CLASS_B(IPAddress))(0xffff00000);

route[0].netDest = 0;
route[0].port = 1;

route[1].netDest = 0;
route[1].port = 2;

route[3].netDest = 0;
route[3].port = 3;

}
```

15  IntelliSense: expression must have pointer-to-object type   c:\Users\lildj_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Lab 2 Routing Table\Lab 2 Routing Table\Main.c 64  8   Lab 2 Routing Table

Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CLASS_A referenced in function _Ouccpy_Routing_Table C:\Users\lildj_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Lab 2 Routing Table\Lab 2 Routing Table\Main.obj   Lab 2 Routing Table

Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CLASS_B referenced in function _Ouccpy_Routing_Table C:\Users\lildj_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Lab 2 Routing Table\Lab 2 Routing Table\Main.obj   Lab 2 Routing Table

Error   9   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   C:\Users\lildj_000\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Lab 2 Routing Table\Debug\Lab 2 Routing Table.exe  1   1   Lab 2 Routing Table

Comment: The error messages mean what they say. They're telling you it doesn't know what `CLASS_A` and `CLASS_B` are. Where are `CLASS_A` and `CLASS_B` defined?

Comment: They aren't being defined anywhere! @lurker if you can point me into the right direction as to where they should be?

Comment: You must be missing a header file, or you need to define them yourself. Your `#include "stdlib.h"` and `#include "string.h"` should probably be `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <string.h>` if they're standard headers. (But they won't define `CLASS_A` or `CLASS_B`.) Were you given a header file as part of your lab? And your `if (CLASS_A(...))...` and `if (CLASS_B(...))...` syntax is all awry. Those statements don't mean anything. Did you type those correctly?

Comment: @DarJude We can't tell you that. They are probably defined as a macros in one of the header files provided as part of the lab. Or you are expected to define it. We really don't know as we don't have the lab question and context.

Comment: We were expected to come up with the header files by our selves @kaylum.

Comment: @DarJude Well then that's the answer to your question "where they should be?". You can define them as macros in a header file that you `#include` into your source file. Or you can define them at the top of your current source file if the macros don't need to be used anywhere else (best practice would generally be to put it into a header file though).

Comment: Is this the actual code to which the messages refer?  The fact that you get linker error suggests that the code compiles, but `if (CLASS_A(IPAddress)) Mask:(0xff0000000);` does not look like valid C code, and you cannot access `route[0].netDest` when route is an `int`.  Moreover the first error is not a compiler or linker error but an VS IntelliSense warning, but it refers to line 64 but line 64 on the code posted does not match the error.  Post real code that is generating the errors described, and post the compiler and linker errors and not the IDE warnings.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As given, there is either a header missing, or you are supposed to write the two macros/functions yourself.

Comment: Further... Why is `IPAddress` passed as a parameter only to be immediately overwritten by another parameter!?

Comment: I have no Idea, I'm trying to understand what i'm doing, but I cant understand it.

Comment: @kaylum he never tough us about Marcos.

Comment: @DarJude Then write a function. Macro was just a suggestion.

Comment: @kaylum what function am I writing again? Just so I understand what i'm doing.

Comment: `CLASS_A` and `CLASS_B` for starters. Why did you call those in the first place if you don't know where they come from and haven't defined them yourself?